# Cocoa-UI : Delayed performSelector .... delayed

Tags: multithreading, macos, cocoa, selector, delay

**The context** :

On my mac app, when i click on a list item, a notification is sent to an object which does something in the background while on the UI there's a waiting message.
All of this takes place in a window which you can quit by a "Close" button. The button by default is disabled when the notifcation is sent.

What i a want to do is a timeout feature which allows the user to quit this windows after a couple minutes hence enabling the close button.

**The code** :

```
- (IBAction)onChangeOperator:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(timerFired:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    ....
    ....
    //takes time
    ....
}

-(void) timerFired:(NSTimer *) theTimer {
[close_button setEnabled:YES];
}
```

**The problem** :
The button is not enabled until onChangeOperator is finished whereas i want it to be enabled as soon as selector is fired.

I think it's a thread thingy but i can't figure out.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the button to be enabled after 2 seconds, but in fact it is not being enabled until after `onChangeOperator` has finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

> Invokes a method of the receiver on the current thread using the default mode after a delay.

So the current thread is still blocked. You should instead run your expensive operation in `onChangeOperator` on a new thread:

```
- (IBAction)onChangeOperator:(id)sender 
{     
    [self performSelector:@selector(timerFired:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doUpdates) withObject:nil];
}

-(void) timerFired:(NSTimer *) theTimer 
{ 
    [close_button setEnabled:YES]; 
} 

-(void)doUpdates
{
    .... stuff that takes time....
}
```

Comment: That's what i found&tried, but it doesn't work. Can't thread my operation, all my app is monothreaded therefore the doUpdates crashes.
Thanks anyway, i'll find an other way or correct that design flaw.

Comment: It may be worth asking a new question to find out why you can't do your other things in the background thread.